# generating graph from matrix

Tags: r, plot, conditional-statements

Using following data:

```
group   G   t1  t2  d1  d2  d3  ta  da  tc  dc  tp  dp  z1  z2  z3  z4  z5  z6  z7  z8  z9  z10
1   1   2081    2081    0   0   0   67  1   121 1   13  1   26  33  1   0   1   1   98  0   1   0
2   1   1602    1602    0   0   0   1602    0   139 1   18  1   21  37  1   1   0   0   1720    0   1   0
3   1   1496    1496    0   0   0   1496    0   307 1   12  1   26  35  1   1   1   0   127 0   1   0
4   1   1462    1462    0   0   0   70  1   95  1   13  1   17  21  0   1   0   0   168 0   1   0
5   1   1433    1433    0   0   0   1433    0   236 1   12  1   32  36  1   1   1   1   93  0   1   0
6   1   1377    1377    0   0   0   1377    0   123 1   12  1   22  31  1   1   1   1   2187    0   1   0
7   1   1330    1330    0   0   0   1330    0   96  1   17  1   20  17  1   0   1   1   1006    0   1   0
8   1   996 996 0   0   0   72  1   121 1   12  1   22  24  1   0   0   0   1319    0   1   0
9   1   226 226 0   0   0   226 0   226 0   10  1   18  21  0   1   0   0   208 0   1   0
10  1   1199    1199    0   0   0   1199    0   91  1   29  1   24  40  1   1   0   1   174 0   3   1
11  1   1111    1111    0   0   0   1111    0   1111    0   22  1   19  28  1   1   0   1   236 0   3   1
12  1   530 530 0   0   0   38  1   84  1   34  1   17  28  1   1   0   0   151 0   3   1
13  1   1182    1182    0   0   0   1182    0   112 1   22  1   24  23  0   0   0   1   203 0   2   1
14  1   1167    1167    0   0   0   39  1   487 1   1167    0   27  22  0   1   1   1   191 0   2   1
15  1   418 418 1   0   1   418 0   220 1   21  1   18  14  1   1   0   0   110 0   1   0
16  1   417 383 1   1   1   417 0   417 0   16  1   15  20  1   1   0   0   824 0   1   0
17  1   276 276 1   0   1   276 0   81  1   21  1   18  5   0   0   0   0   146 0   1   0
18  1   156 104 1   1   1   28  1   156 0   20  1   20  33  1   1   0   1   85  0   1   0
19  1   781 609 1   1   1   781 0   781 0   26  1   27  27  1   0   1   1   187 0   1   0
20  1   172 172 1   0   1   22  1   172 0   37  1   40  37  0   0   0   1   129 0   1   0
21  1   487 487 1   0   1   487 0   76  1   22  1   22  20  1   1   0   0   128 0   1   0
22  1   716 662 1   1   1   716 0   716 0   17  1   28  32  1   1   0   0   84  0   1   0
23  1   194 194 1   0   1   194 0   94  1   25  1   26  32  0   1   0   0   329 0   1   0
24  1   371 230 1   1   1   371 0   184 1   9   1   39  31  0   1   0   1   147 0   1   0
25  1   526 526 1   0   1   526 0   121 1   11  1   15  20  1   1   0   0   943 0   1   0
26  1   122 122 1   0   1   88  1   122 0   13  1   20  26  1   0   0   1   2616    0   1   0
27  1   1279    129 1   1   1   1279    0   1279    0   22  1   17  20  0   0   0   0   937 0   3   1
28  1   110 74  1   1   1   110 0   110 0   49  1   28  25  1   0   1   0   303 0   3   1
29  1   243 122 1   1   1   243 0   243 0   23  1   37  38  0   1   1   1   170 0   3   1
30  1   86  86  1   0   1   86  0   86  0   86  0   17  26  1   0   1   0   239 0   3   1
31  1   466 466 1   0   1   466 0   119 1   100 1   15  18  1   1   0   0   508 0   3   1
32  1   262 192 1   1   1   10  1   84  1   59  1   29  32  1   1   1   0   74  0   3   1
33  1   162 109 1   1   1   162 0   162 0   40  1   36  43  1   1   1   0   393 0   2   1
34  1   262 55  1   1   1   262 0   262 0   24  1   23  16  0   1   1   1   331 0   2   1
35  1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   42  48  1   1   0   0   196 0   2   1
36  1   107 107 1   0   1   107 0   107 0   107 0   30  19  1   1   1   1   178 0   2   1
37  1   269 110 1   1   1   269 0   120 1   27  1   29  20  0   1   1   1   361 0   2   1
38  1   350 332 1   0   1   350 0   350 0   33  1   22  20  1   0   0   0   834 0   2   1
```

I want to generate following plot:

[image]

but I don't know how to do the conditional probability.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to read [how to ask a question here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you could consider elaborating on your problem a little bit more. Leaving on side analytical particularities, the graph you linked is simply a line chart with groups. Arriving at it would imply transforming the data, but it's not clear from the question what do you want to achieve. I would suggest breaking down this problem into two chunks **1)** [calculations](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/how-to-create-a-dataset-with-conditional-probability) **2)** visualisation. Also, please consider embedding your graph, if the link breaks you post will be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I had to use the cprob package in R. Thanks for the help.